# GWT: How to use with 3rd party jars that require XML configuration?

Tags: java, xml, gwt, configuration, ehcache

I'm trying to see if I can get GWT to work with Ehcache for a powerful client-side caching solution.

But Ehcache requires that a file called `ehcache.xml` be on the runtime classpath. At runtime, when a cache manager/factory attempts to create a cache (in the Java code), it looks to the classpath for this XML descriptor and builds a cache with the specifications it contains.

**But how would this work for GWT**? Come runtime, the Java code has already been translated to JavaScript! How would the JS code know to look for `ehcache.xml`? And not just for Ehcache, but for any 3rd party JAR that requires some kind of runtime configuration (XML, PROPERTIES, or otherwise) file to work?

Comment: I'd be pretty surprised if you could get this to work.  My impression of Ehcache is that it uses a lot of heavy-duty stuff -- e.g. concurrency -- that you'll have trouble getting to work on GWT.

Comment: Thanks @LouisWasserman - duly noted and if its too heavy-duty I'll just roll my own hashmap solution (or maybe find some other caching lib that works with GWT). I'm more or less interested in how 3rd party JARs that require XML (or other) runtime configs can work with GWT.

Comment: I would be surprised as well. I don't know hoe Ehcache is implemented but considering the availability of tools and libraries for the client side implementation of GWT, my guess is that even if you could somehow upload the xml, the ehcache methods would not be able to translate to javascript and the whole try would fail.

Comment: Hi TicketMonster, it would be nice if you updated what solution did you come up with eventually :)

Answer (score 0):

You might try using REST and EhCache Server:

http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2010_03_01_archive.html